# How to dispatch action from a javascript file (instead of a vue component)?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have one module(javascript file) outside of vue context. i need to dispatch action from this javascript file. is it possible ? if yes, then how ?

jsfile.js(Javascript file)

```
const detail = {};

detail.validateLocation = (location) => {
  // need to dispatch one action from here.
  // dispatch('SET_LOCATION', {city: 'California'})
  // how to dispatch action ?
}

export default detail;
```

action.js

```
export default {
  SET_LOCATION: ({ commit}, data) => {
    commit('SET_LOCATION', data);
  },
}
```

store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import actions from './actions';
import mutations from './mutations';
import getters from './getters';
export function createStore() {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {},
    state: {
      location: null
    },
    actions,
    mutations,
    getters,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

First, create the store in **store.js**.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import actions from './actions';
import mutations from './mutations';
import getters from './getters';

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {},
    state: {
      location: null
    },
    actions,
    mutations,
    getters,
  });

export default store
```

Then, import the store into **jsfile.js** and use it.

```
import store from "./store"

const detail = {};

detail.validateLocation = (location) => {
  // Use imported store
  store.dispatch('SET_LOCATION', {city: 'California'})
}

export default detail;
```

Assuming you have a main or index file that creates your Vue instance, you now likely need to change the import from importing the create function to simply importing the store.

Comment: I am doing like:
import { createStore } from '../store';
const store = createStore();
store.dispatch('SET_LOCATION', {city: 'California'});
but it's not working

Comment: @MukundKumar Don't do that. Just `import store from "./store"`. There is no reason you need to export a function to create the store. Just import the store. If you export a create function and create a store in multiple files, you will end up with multiple stores.

Comment: but i am wrapping new Vuex.Store() in a createStore function. so it should work.

Comment: @MukundKumar Do you *want* more than one store?

Comment: No, I just want same store, so that i can dispatch one action.

Comment: @MukundKumar Then you do not want to export a function that creates the store. Here is a working example. https://codesandbox.io/s/pp3q973k6j

Comment: To anyone else with this issue- if you are using modules, you must import the base store and reference the module via forward slash notation like `store.dispatch('user/markNotificationAsRead', notification);`

Comment: Whether or not a store creating function is exported or the store itself is exported as an already-created singleton is not important. What matters is the same store that gets created is utilized by both Vue and the separate js file. If you want to create a store with a function, that's fine - you can continue doing that. Just make sure you get the same store into jsfile.js. You can export a function from jsfile.js, which can return an interface after receiving its dependencies as an input (which would include `store`).

Comment: @dvlsg There's no reason to export a function to create a store unless at some point you want more than one store. OP wanted one store.